# Right way to specify podAffinity/nodeSelector for kibana sub-chart from bitnami elasticsearch chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I have just started using [Bitnami Elasticssearch chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/elasticsearch) to deploy my elasticsearch cluster on AWS EKS. I have been able to deploy it successfully using the values-production.yaml file.

However, there are two issues that I'd like to address:

1. Specify node selector/pod affinity for metrics pod: I see that the [templates/metrics-deploy.yaml](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/elasticsearch/templates/metrics-deploy.yaml) doesn't handle both, node selector or pod affinity. I want my metrics container to run on one of the Elasticsearch master nodes. Does that mean I have to modify the metrics-deploy.yaml file?
2. Specify pod affinity for [kibana sub-chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kibana): Ideally, kibana pod should be co-located with the coordinating/client node. I thought that would be the default behavior but it isn't so. How do I specify pod affinity for the kibana sub-chart from inside my customized values-production.yaml file (for Elasticsearch). I suppose I can create my own helm chart from bitnami but that sounds like a lot of work for a simple ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Helm has recently introduced functionality to overwrite un-templated values. It is called [post rendering](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#post-rendering) and allows you to integrate third party tools like [kustomize](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize) to overwrite yaml files. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/thomastaylor312/advanced-helm-demos/tree/master/post-render).
2. To overwrite templated values from a sub-chart from the command line, simply prefix them with the name of the sub-chart, so in case of the node affinity setting, this would be: `--set kibana.affinity`

Answer (score 0):

Found this: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/
to specify values for sub-chart